# using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my page. with two textboxes and one textarea.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><b>Search Criteria</b></legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>                
                Find Text: 
                <input type="text" style="width:150px" id="txtFind"/>
                <input type="button" id="btnfind" value=" Find "/>                           
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Replace Text: 
                <input type="text" style="width:150px" id="Text1"/>
                <input type="button" value="Replace Text" id="btnReplace"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<br />
<fieldset>
    <legend><b>Result</b></legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>    
                <%:Html.TextArea("Hello ASP.NET here")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

in my first textbox if I enter "*here*" then I click the **Find** button it should find the text

if I enter "*MVC*" on second text box click **Replace Text**  button it should replace the text "*here*" to "*MVC*" ("Hello ASP.NET MVC").,

Please can any one help me out? How to do this with javascript or jquery?

Thanks

Comment: So you want the text area to read "Hello ASP.NET MVC" instead? Your requirements are very unclear.

Comment: Marc thanks for your responce. my problem is I am dispalying text in the textarea from table. so when I want to find some text in the textare I just type that text in find textbox and I will enter replacement text in the second textbox and If I click replace text button it should replace find text with replace text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/DD7t5/

using jQuery and a [highlight jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

```
var $result = $('#result'),
    $txtFind = $('#txtFind'),
    $txtReplace = $('#txtReplace');

$('#btnFind').click(function() {
    $result.removeHighlight();

    var findValue = $txtFind.val();

    if (findValue.length > 0) {
        $result.highlight(findValue) // find and highlight
    }
});

$('#btnReplace').click(function() {
    $result.text($result.text().replace(eval('/' + $txtFind.val() + '/gi'), 
        $txtReplace.val())); // replace
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Asuming your textarea has `id="textarea"`, you should do this:

```
$("#btnfind").click(function(){   
   var find = $("#txtFind").val();
   var replace = $("Text1").val(); 
   var text = $("#textarea").val();
   while(text.indexOf(find) >= 0){
      text = text.replace(find, replace);
   }
   $("#textarea").val(text);
});
```

(Note that we're not using Regular expressions to replace because the text to find is dynamic so we'd have to escape the 'find' text).

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks Edgar, Can you please tell me how to do with Regexp? bec find element I need to highlight with some color?

Comment: I need to find and replace the text in multiple places in my textarea box.?

Comment: You're welcome, Sandy. The code of my answer replaces all occurrences of the searched string.
However, with regexp, **instead of the whole** `while` block it would be: `text = text.replace(new Regexp(find, "g"), replace);` but it would have problems when you search characters as /, [, ], -, etc. The current code of my answer doesn't have that problem